# different versions of python on the same windows10 computer confusions

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am setting up tensorflow-gpu version. I had python 3.6.4 installed before but it is said this version doesn't support my current NVDIA GPU so i downloaded 3.5.x which works perfectly right now. So I have 3 versions right now, 2.7 3.5,3.6.

But the python version management now is a mess. Since I have changed my environment variable to

```
E:\Python35\Scripts
```

typing 'python' won't invoke python shell now, but 'py' does.And it seems to invoke the newest 3,6.4 version. I actually hope it could invoke 3.5.x instead. 
But the weird thing is when i use pip3 to install no matter what, it would use the pip3 of python35. I guess thats because I set python35 in environment variable.

But to summarize my questions:

1.if assume I set both pip3 of python36 and python35 in my %PATH%, which one it will use when i type pip3?

2.why 'py' command will work? how to make pip3 and python keyword work at the same time? pip3 needs E:\Python35\Scripts while 'python' will need E:\Python35 which seems to be a conflict.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but i am new to this. Would also appreciate some documentations where the explanations are, there are just plenty of things on the internet and would cost hours to find.

Thanks in advance!
Guess i am spending more time on trying to save a little of not typing py -3.5 or py -3.6 everytime...

Comment: I highly recommend using [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/?lang=en-us) and create environments to avoid these conflicts

Comment: regards to your first question it will use the first pip3 it finds in PATH. So if python36 path is above python35 path in %PATH% then it will use the pip3 from python36.